# Car loan calculator in Javascript displays nothing

Tags: javascript, calculator

I hope someone can help with this:

I am currently working on a motor dealership website. On this website is a car loan calculator that calculates your monthly repayments. I have successfully created a basic calculator that calculates the correct amount.

The client isn't happy with that. They want a more advanced calculator that calculates the monthly repayments with balloon considerations and a deposit and initiation and admin fees.

I altered the code to reflect that, but now the thing won't work anymore. I can't find any error in my code.

Here's the Javascript that's supposed to do the calculation:

```
function calculate() {
        // Get the user's input from the form. Assume it is all valid.
        // Convert interest from a percentage to a decimal, and convert from
        // an annual rate to a monthly rate. Convert payment period in years
        // to the number of monthly payments.
        var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
        var lessDeposit = document.loandata.deposit.value;
        var adminFee = document.loandata.admin.value;
        var initiationFee = document.loandata.initiation.value;
        var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
        var payments = document.loandata.years.value * 12;
        var balloonPercent = document.loandata.balloon.value / 100;

        // Now compute the monthly payment figure, using esoteric math.
        var balloonFinal = (principal * balloonPercent);
        var totalPrincipal = (principal + initiationFee + balloonfinal - lessDeposit);
        var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
        var monthly = (totalPrincipal*x*interest)/(x-1);

        // Check that the result is a finite number. If so, display the results
        if (!isNaN(monthly) && 
            (monthly != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
            (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {

            document.loandata.payment.value = round(monthly + adminFee);
            document.loandata.total.value = round(monthly * payments);
            document.loandata.totalinterest.value = 
                round((monthly * payments) - principal);
        }
        // Otherwise, the user's input was probably invalid, so don't
        // display anything.
        else {
            document.loandata.payment.value = "";
            document.loandata.total.value = "";
            document.loandata.totalinterest.value = "";
        }
}

// This simple method rounds a number to two decimal places.
function round(x) {
    return Math.round(x*100)/100;
}
```

Also, if possible, there needs to be some validation. Like purchase price, interest rate and payment period are required fields. But the rest are not. So if someone fills in the required fields but not the rest, the calculator still needs to work, but if someone does NOT complete one of the required fields, they need to be prompted to do so.

For those who don't know what a balloon payment is, here's an example;
Purchase Price is R117 000
You decide on a balloon payment of 30%. On the initial purchase price, the 30% amounts to R35 100. This amount is then subtracted from your initial purchase price so that means your purchase is now R81 900. After that comes the deposit, which is subtracted, and the extras and the admin and initiation fees. So the monthly repayments are calculated using this new purchase price of R81 900 + extras - deposit (if any). For interest sake, after your contract ends, you have to pay the balloon amount in full or re-finance the vehicle.

PS: I'm a complete newbie when it comes to JavaScript. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your developer console, are there any errors? Press f12 to view it in chrome.

Comment: Hi, I can't see any errors.

Comment: Maybe this question is stale, but you may consider separating retrieval of values in the dom, the calculation, and updating the dom with the results of the calculation. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If the result is nothing, one of these three conditions is likely triggering the else statement:

```
if (!isNaN(monthly) && 
    (monthly != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
    (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the JS, you need to change `balloonfinal` to be `balloonFinal` with a capital F in the `var totalPrincipal =` line of code.

The `principal`, `lessDeposit`, `adminFee`, `initiationFee` may also need to be typecast as an integer/float.